# Add 'comic sans ms' font in pdf using pisa library in django

Tags: django, fonts, pdf-generation, pisa

i want to add "comic" font in pdf file by using Pisa in django. Pisa  default font is Helvetica for text, but i want more fonts in my generated pdf, like arial,comic, symbol, verdana etc.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi i got the answer, if you are using editor, then save its out put in "contents" string. Then following code will work.

```
contents = "<html><head><style type='text/css'>@font-face {font-family: comic sans ms; src: url(media/fonts/comic.ttf);}</style></head><body> " + contents + " </body></html>"
template = Template(contents)

context = Context()
template_rendered = template.render(context)

name="mypdf.pdf"

import ho.pisa as pisa
pfile = file(name, 'wb')
pisa.CreatePDF(template_rendered.encode("UTF-8"), pfile ,encoding='UTF-8')
pfile.close()
```

Hopefully many others answers exist but in my case, using tinymce editor, this solution works.

Comment: Just to help others, too - note that pisa seems to use the project root as its relative base of the url() call.